# How to display a Google Maps route in a WebBrowser on a C# Windows form

Tags: c#, google-maps

My problem is the following:

I have a list of addresses and I would like to show the Google Map with the route on a WebBrowser object in my C# Windows Form.

My list is that:

```
        List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
        addresses.Add("Milano");
        addresses.Add("Bologna");
        addresses.Add("Venezia");
        addresses.Add("Milano");
```

Have you some suggestion to show the map on the WebBrowser?

Thanks

Comment: It would be the same if you do it in a normal browser so all examples will probably work.

Comment: @Eser Thanks, but I also need to show the correct route, not only a straight line from/to the locations.

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate to this url in your webbrowser control.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Milano/Bologna/Venezia/Milano
```

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Milano/Bologna/Venezia/Milano

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + string.Join("/", addresses);
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

Comment: Yeah! That's what I wanted. Thanks Eser.. I think the webBrowser object uses as a default browser Internet Explorer, but it's not compatible with GoogleMaps. Do you know how set as a default browser Google Chrome?